# Python Tkinter append the output to a list

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to display a while true loop's output on a list on tkinter that would update the output at the end of the list. in the code below, I am listing the numbers from one to 100, but how could I make it so that it updates one number at a time for an infinite while true loop?

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
i = 0
while i < 100:
    i = i + 1
    listbox.insert(END, str(i))
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I have a separate python script that pulls data from twitter, and I would like to display the output on a GUI rather than the console. inside the while true loop, I would update the text, and set it at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mainloop as your loop, and use the `after` method to call a function every second. Here's a minimal example:

```
from Tkinter import *

COUNT = 0
def add_one():
    global COUNT
    COUNT += 1
    listbox.insert(END, str(COUNT))
    master.after(1000, add_one)

master = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

add_one()
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```